# Books on complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, riemann-surfaces, sheaf-theory

Is there any book on $1$-dimensional complex analysis, where all is written in the language of sheaf theory? It's clear, that a lot of constructions can be formulated in simplier way using it. There are a lot of such books of n-dimensional complex analysis. And what about 1-dimensional?

Comment: What is 1D complex analysis? Complex numbers have a real and an imaginary part, so that is 2D. If you have a complex valued function, then it becomes 4D.

Comment: @glebovg Probably 1D over $\mathbb{C}$...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Robert Gunning's "old" Princeton-Yellow-Series book "Intro to Riemann Surfaces" (the first in a sequence of several books he wrote about Riemann surfaces and related matters...) systematically uses sheaf theory (albeit not the derived-functor version, but Cech). In my opinion, it wonderfully illustrates how sheaf theory can be used, in a very tangible example.

Comment: And what about ramification of analytical functions, Grothendieck's 'children's drawings'?

Comment: The Gunning book is mostly "global", and "algebraic" in the sense that it addresses _compact_ (connected) Riemann surfaces. In one complex variable, there's not a lot to worry about "ramification", of course. He does Riemann-Roch, Serre duality, things like that.

Comment: Thank you! I know Riemann-Roch and Serre duality only in algebraic case. It would be interesting to study it in complex case.